# measure network traffic separately

Tags: iphone, networking, ios4, network-programming

i want to measure network traffic of

> GPS , 3G and WiFi separately
>
> Application vise separately

in iphone , can any one suggest me the **APIs** to perform all above task or show me some **example** or **road map**.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get those figures from the publicly documented APIs (and I don't quite know what you mean by 'network traffic of GPS', because GPS isn't a network protocol). So the answer to your question is: no, nobody can suggest it, because it's not possible within the public APIs.

You can probably do it using undocumented classes or on jailbroken devices, but if you're looking to put your app on the app store there's no point considering that because it will just get rejected.

Comment: there is a one application exist on apple store 
so i dont think it will need jail break 
http://www.hedonicsoft.com/prod/iphone/download-meter/

Comment: Several apps on the app store use undocumented methods and have slipped through the review cracks. What I'm saying is there is no *publicly documented* way to do what you want.

Comment: Ohhh .. well sorry but i didn't know about all these matter. So do you know how to get this thing done via private APIs ?

Comment: Well i have asked the support department of download meter they don't use any private apis or jailbreking.. so except showing data traffic application vise other things are still possible to implement and get approved. but i really didn't find the way to get it done